# I cannot find an img element just created in document

Tags: javascript

I need to create an img element, set it an ID and then find it using the document function getElementById

The first console displays correctly the ID of the element but the second one says null

```
const image = document.createElement("IMG")
image.id="inn"
console.log(image.id)//this is fine
const innUI = document.getElementById('inn')
console.log(innUI.id)//i get null here
```

Is it because i need to append the element to any part of the HTML?

Comment: Why would you need to find it? You already have it referenced by `innUI`.

Comment: ...but the DOM is a tree structure of objects (DOM nodes). Simply creating a new DOM node doesn't put it in the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the object in DOM then only you can find it using getElementById

```js
  
   const image = document.createElement("IMG")
image.id="inn"
document.body.appendChild(image);
console.log(image.id)//this is fine
const innUI = document.getElementById('inn')
console.log(innUI.id)//i get null here
```